# Select field to create or update has_many records on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, multi-select

I want to have a simple select field that allows users to choose some users to be on a job's team.

```
#jobs.rb
class Job < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :team_members
end

#jobs_controller.rb
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    if @job.update_attributes(job_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Job Saved"
      redirect_to job_path(@job)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Job Not Saved"
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def job_params
     params.require(:job).permit(     
     team_member_ids: []

    )
   end
end

# jobs/edit.html.erb
<%= f.select :team_member_ids, User.all, {:include_blank => "None"},{ :multiple => true} %>
```

This gives me an error

Couldn't find TeamMembers with ids 117, 23, 30.

Am I missing something simple here? Or is the wrong approach to managing the data in the form?

Update, params hash:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xxxx",
 "job"=>
  {
   "jobtype"=>"Cutting",
   "status"=>"Not_Started",   
   "team_member_ids"=>["", "117", "23", "30"]},
 "commit"=>"Update Job",
 "id"=>"84"}
```

Comment: Can you please show the params hash?

Comment: As per the error, TeamMember model doesn't have records with ids 117, 23, 30. Can you check that in DB

Answer (score 0):

Oops, This was a bit silly.

The id's are user id's, but I was passing them as team_member ids.  Where team_member is the join table. 
Fix was:

```
#add to job.rb
has_many :users, through: :team_members

# update jobs_controller.rb

private
  def job_params
     params.require(:job).permit(     
     user_ids: []
    )
   end
# update form field:
<%= f.select :user_ids, User.all,{:include_blank => "None"},{ :multiple => true} %>
```